# php notification system muted

Tags: php, date

i made an notification system and i made a button for turn off notification for 
1 hour
to 08:00 am
and at leas until i turn notification on again

my idea its save the data of notification in database and when other user send notification i test if date greater then notification date that's mean the notification was turned on again but if some one turned notification for 1 hour and its in china the hour 07:00 am and another user from USA send and notification 
this will not work because date was different any one have idea for turn off notification 
1 - for 1 hour
2 - to 8 am 
3 - until back its on again

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add a list box near to the button and include those timezones which is supported by Php. Here is list;
http://php.net/manual/tr/timezones.others.php

If you do not want to take the time zone from user. You can detect it from IP. There are several ways to do that. You can google it to learn.

Then add a control function and pass the userTimeZone parameter to the function like that;

```
<?php
public function control($userTimeZone){
date_default_timezone_set($userTimeZone); //for example "Asia/Dhaka"  We set the time zone here which is taken from user.
$hour = date('H');  //get the hour
if($hour>=1 && hour=<7){
//turnoff notifications
}
else{
  }
}
?>
```